# Using x:Phase with image inside ImageBrush

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, xbind

I design an UWP app and I glad to use new features such as `x:Bind` and `x:Phase`.

I have a simple model (containers such as `Grid` and `StackPanel` omitted):

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" x:Phase="0" />
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Date}" x:Phase="1" />

<Ellipse Stretch="UniformToFill">
   <Ellipse.Fill>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind Image}" />
   </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

So I want to specify `x:Phase` for image but I can't do this due to obvious constraints: `x:Phase` is presented only for `FrameworkElement` so I can't specify `ImageBrush`'s `x:Phase` and it has to be specified with `x:Bind` so I can't use it on `Ellipse`.

It's weird to use `x:Phase` with text and allow to image load first. How to solve this?

**UPD:** There is a hack!

Set any unimportant property to its default value through `x:Bind` to fake model property. One code line instead of dozens.

```
<Ellipse Stretch="UniformToFill" CanDrag="{x:Bind PlaceholderCanDrag}" x:Phase="2">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind Image}" />
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with Image and DecodePixelWidth/Height - here's how I solved it (I know you found a solution, but maybe it will help others) http://igrali.com/2015/11/15/image-attached-properties-to-make-x-phase-work-with-bitmapimage-source/

Comment: Your solution is more legal, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x:Phase has been introduced to simplify the phasing process, in other words so that you don't need to write code yourself.

SO 'maybe' you could try to implement the phasing again through code?
I know it's a lot of work but could be the only thing that would work with Ellipse.

A good start example can be found here http://mcnextpost.com/2015/11/10/uwpxaml-compiled-binding-incremental-rendering-with-xphase/

You'll need to hook up to the GridView / ListView `ContainerContentChanging` event and work through the phases from there

Comment: Yes, I've implemented this before, but I hoped there is another way to do that. Writing such code is too big price for just a rounded image, isn't it?

Comment: True! Let's hope they will expand on this in future XAML releases.

Comment: We can hack this! If we initialize some Ellipse property using `x:Bind` with the default value stored in model, we could use `x:Phase`